# is it possible to rescale a snap svg canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, snap.svg

I have a snap svg canvas area that sits on top of a dynamically loaded image and covers it entirely. sometimes the image and svg area extend off the right side of the screen. this is desirable. however at one point in the application i'd like to use jquery or javascript to temporarily shrink the image and svg area down proportionally so that everything fits into the visible screen area.

is this possible? if so how might it be done?

here's the setup

```
<div id="holder" style="align:center; width: <%=stageW%>px; height: <%=stageH%>px;" >
   <img src="<%=img%>" class="image"  id="img" width="<%=stageW%>" height="<%=stageH%>"/>
   <svg id="svg"></svg>
</div>
```

the stageH and stageW variables are classic ASP and are the dimensions of the jpg. the svg area takes on the same size and is filled with user-drawn shapes traced over the top of the image.

i'd like to find a way to reduce the image and svg contents proportianately to fit within the window's width.

Comment: its not clear what elements you have to change thats setting the current sizes without any code. Maybe its the css and the div or whatever you are using.

Comment: i've added the setup to my question.

Comment: Could you do something like put the svg inside a div and then use javascript to add a class to the div that limits its size?